# PowerShell ProxyEmail Address

Tags: powershell, csv, active-directory

Currently I have the script below, which will compare email addresses in the CSV to the main mail address in ActiveDirectory, but it does not take proxy addresses into account. For instance, if Mary Smith had an email address Mary.Smith@abc.com, then Mary got married and her last name changed to Jones. Her standard email address is still Mary.smith@abc.com but she now has a proxy called mary.jones@abc.com.

How do I use this script to also validate against the proxyaddresses? Preferably without a huge hit to Active Directory .

```
$path = "H:\users.csv"
$csv = Import-Csv $path 
Import-Module ActiveDirectory

foreach ($line in $csv)
{
    $User = Get-ADUser -LDAPFilter "(&(objectclass=user)(mail=$($line.Email)))"
    if ($User -eq $Null) {"User does not exist in AD   " + $line.Email }
    else {"User found in AD  - " + $line.Email}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AD has a **proxyAddresses** attribute for mail-enabled users, which includes the primary SMTP address as well as any aliases. Change your **-LDAPFilter** argument to this:

```
"(&(objectclass=user)(proxyAddresses=*$($line.Email)*))"
```

BTW, it's possible for the **mail** attribute to differ from the primary SMTP address in **proxyAddresses**, because the latter is enforced by Exchange but the former can be changed at will outside Exchange. It's not likely if you have a single Exchange organization integrated with the domain, but if you're concerned about that possibility you can use this filter:

```
"(&(objectclass=user)(|(mail=$($line.Email))(proxyAddresses=*$($line.Email)*)))"
```

Comment: Okay so I tested this one out and yes it does work but for a list of 8 email addresses (Both versions your provided) it takes 15 seconds for the script to run through them all. I Know this was not a part of the question but is there a way to speed that up?

Comment: Due simply for the fact that this met the initial question and it does work and due to restrictions I cannot test out the only other suggested resolution I am marking this as answered

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're running Exchange, you'd be much better off using the Exchange Get-Recipient cmdlet for this. Exchange maintains a database indexed by SMTP address, so those lookups are immediate.  AD does not, so it must search all the ProxyAddreses of every user looking for a match.

```
$ExSession =   new-pssession -configurationname Microsoft.Exchange -ConnectionURI http://<ExchangeServerName>/powershell/ -authentication kerberos 
foreach($line in $csv)
 { 
  if (Invoke-Command {Get-Recipient $args[0]} -ArgumentList $line.Email -Session $ExSession -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue)
   {"User exists in AD"}
   else {"User not found in AD"}
 }
```

Substitue the name of one of your Exchange servers for  in the new-pssession command.

Comment: I get access denied error messages. I also tried replacing -authentication kerberos with -credential <domain>\<user> and got this error 
The WinRM client cannot process the 
request. The WinRM client tried to use Negotiate authentication mechanism, but the destination computer

Comment: The account you use needs to be a member of an Exchange RBAC role with permission to run the cmdlet.  View-Only Organization Management will work.  You basically just need the View-Only Recipients right.  You can specify alternate credentials on the New-PSSession cmdlet if you have another account you want to use.

Comment: So according to our Exchange Admin I would have to have a Remote Session which they will not allow for. Fully understandable for them not allowing for that. But due to not having the remote session I cannot test this one out

Comment: I'm an Exchange admin, and I don't see why this would be a problem.  Doing those lookups would impose a trival load on an Exchange server while removing a substantial load from a DC.  I'd think any Exchange admin would see that as a good thing. If you're only granted View-Only rights, all you can do is retrieve information, you can't update anything.